# SQL query to select all the articles with the given tags from a pivot table

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have an `article` table and a `tag` table in PostgreQL 13. `article` and `tag` have a many-to-many relation. A pivot table `article_tag` is created with the following schema:

```
- FOREIGN KEY article_id REFERENCES article(id)
- FOREIGN KEY tag_id REFERENCES tag(id)
```

Now given a list of tag ids (ID1, ID2, ID3...), how can I query all the articles that have those tags? I thought of using something like:

```
SELECT article_id FROM (
  SELECT article_id FROM article_tag WHERE tag_id = ID2
) WEHRE tag_id = ID1;
```

But if the tag id list is long, this query will be nested in a complicated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select article_id
from article_tag
where tag_id in (id1, id2, id3)
group by article_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Note the `3` is the size of the `in` list.  You can also express this using arrays, which simplifies the query:

```
select article_id
from article_tag
where tag_id = any (:id_array)
group by article_id
having count(*) = cardinality(:id_array);
```